# Automating exporting of a view

Tags: 7, views, rules, importing-exporting

I'm running a system where has a view with export functionality in order to export results in xls format.

Is there anyway I can automate it so every week it auto generates a report and email it.

I'm guessing I can use rules to do it but dont know how.

Thanks

Comment: Try to set a cron job by using [elysia_cron](https://www.drupal.org/project/elysia_cron)

Comment: thank for your quick reply @mchar . I can try installing the elysia_cron but what sort of commands/script do I need to use to export data from a view.

Comment: I'm not sure how to even configure rules to do this.

Comment: Are you able to install additional software to your server? E.g. mailx/mutt/mpack? And most importantly, are you interested in a *nix/terminal-based solution?

Comment: Another important question: Which contrib module are you using to generated the XLS in the first place?

Comment: @StefanosPetrakis I'm using views_data_export to export the results. I'm happy if I can schedule a job to download the results on server instead of emailing them.

Comment: I'm also aware that views_data_export supports Drush so now trying to find a way so I can use cron to execute a drush command in order to automate the download at a specific location within the server.

Comment: Yes, that's what I was going for. Still open: Can you install some additional software on your server like mail/mailx/mutt/mpack? Or, do you have one of them already available?

Comment: @StefanosPetrakis I've already got email working fine and can add any additional modules if need to.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51446/discussion-between-stefanos-petrakis-and-ozyy).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the [views_data_export](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_data_export) module and you have command line access you can try the following:

```
cd [your_drupal_docroot] 
drush views-data-export [view-name] [display-id] > [path-to-output-file]
```

You could then add this to cron as a one-liner, e.g. this would run every Monday at 5:59 AM:

```
59 5 * * 0 cd [absolute_path_to_drupal_docroot] && drush views-data-export [view-name] [display-id] > [path-to-output-file]
```